# Use regex to trim potential trailing slash and/or querystring from URI string

Tags: php, regex, uri, preg-replace, sanitization

I have the following URIs:

- `/controller/method/arg1/arg2`
- `/controller/method/arg1/arg2/` **<- trailing slash**
- `/controller/method/arg1/arg2?param=1&param=2` **<- trailing query string**

I need a regular expression to extract always `/controller/method/arg1/arg2`, while keeping in mind that it can end with `/`, `?` or `?` **+ some characters**.

This:

```
^\/.*\??
```

is not working for me, as it is taking the chars before `?`.

Ideally, I don't want the trailing `/` or `?`, but if the pattern leaves them behind, I'll just trim them after the regex replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure one can think of more fancy regex's, but as far as I can see, the simplest possible matching regex would be;

```
^[^?]*
```

It cuts everything after `?` off, and the other matches are - as you say - easily handled by trimming.

A [ReFiddle](http://refiddle.co/gq6) to test with

Comment: @Jerry: if you check the question you'll see that it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no empty directory names in your path, you can use repeated subpatterns to match an optional slash followed by one or more non-question mark, non-slash characters.  After consuming these allowed characters, use `\K` to forget the full string match, then match any remaining characters and replace them with an empty string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qNh4H))

```
$tests = [
    'controller/method/arg1/arg2',
    'controller/method/arg1/arg2/',
    'controller/method/arg1/arg2?param=1&param=2',
    'controller/method/arg1/arg2/?param=1&param=2',
    '/controller/method/arg1/arg2',
    '/controller/method/arg1/arg2/',
    '/controller/method/arg1/arg2?param=1&param=2',
    '/controller/method/arg1/arg2/?param=1&param=2',
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('#(?:/?[^?/]+)+\K.*#', '', $tests)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'controller/method/arg1/arg2',
  1 => 'controller/method/arg1/arg2',
  2 => 'controller/method/arg1/arg2',
  3 => 'controller/method/arg1/arg2',
  4 => '/controller/method/arg1/arg2',
  5 => '/controller/method/arg1/arg2',
  6 => '/controller/method/arg1/arg2',
  7 => '/controller/method/arg1/arg2',
)
```